# I need to build a char array from two integers

Tags: programming, string

My C is rusty, so please forgive this simple problem.

This line works:

`Tft.drawString("Test",200,200,2,WHITE);`

But, this has compile errors:

```
String yStr = "Test";  
Tft.drawString(yStr,200,200,2,WHITE);
```

The function in the library:

```
void drawString(char *string,unsigned int poX, unsigned int poY,unsigned int size,unsigned int fgcolor);
```

The error is **"no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'char*'"**.

Conclusion - I need a character array. Here's what I am trying to accomplish.

I have two integers that I would like to display on my Tft screen. For example, 225 and 250 to be displayed as "225,250".

I haven't figured out a way to build the char array for the `drawString()` function.

Assistance would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for the quick reply Ignacio.
I tried that, but the compiler still doesn't like it.

Here's how I built the string:

```
string stringXY ;
stringXY += xStr;
stringXY += ",";
stringXY += yStr;
Tft.drawString(stringXY.c_str(),200,200,2,RED);
```

Error: **invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]**

I am apparently using `c_str()` wrong?

Comment: The pure c method using a char array rather than a string is to use sprintf: char tmpBuffer[64]; sprintf(tmpBuffer,"%d,%d",xVal,yVal);

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) and then use the `c_str()` method to get the associated `char*`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ignacio.  
I tried that, but the compiler still doesn't like it.

Here's how I built the string:

String stringXY ;
stringXY += xStr;
stringXY += ",";
stringXY += yStr;

Tft.drawString(stringXY.c_str(),200,200,2,RED);  
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

I am apparently using c_str() wrong?

Comment: No, that's a bug in the TFT library. There's no reason that argument should be modified, so it *should* be tagged `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Ignacio.

I changed the function in the library to:

void drawString(**const** char *string,unsigned int poX, unsigned int poY,unsigned int size,unsigned int fgcolor);

This fixed the problem and gave me more confidence in my vague understanding of C.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in your situation is to not use `String` at all (which is preferrable for reasons I won't explain here) and exclusively use plain old C strings and their associated functions:

```
// Define a string buffer to hold the result, ensure it is long enough
// to hold "N1,N2". An additional char must be added to terminate the string with 0
char result[15+1];
unsigned int N1 = ...;
unsigned int N2 = ...;
// Format output as desired
sprintf(result, "%u,%u", N1, N2);
// Now you can use result with drawString
Tft.drawString(result, 200, 200, 2, RED);
```

`sprintf` is a very powerful formatting function that offers you plenty of options.

Note that I took it for granted that your numbers are `unsigned int`; if these were normal `integer` (possibly negative), you should replace `"%u,%u"` with `"%d,%d"`.

Comment: What is the (approximate) overhead of *sprintf* in terms of global/static RAM allocation, dynamic allocation, and program size (flash memory)